# Azure DevOps: How to show wiki pages in own application without the devops main menu?

Tags: url, azure-devops, wiki, azure-devops-wiki

I'd like to show the Azure DevOps Wiki I created for my project within a WPF View with a Browser control. I used the following url:

```
https://dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/_wiki/wikis/KIS.wiki?wikiVersion=GBwikiMaster&pagePath=%2FNew%20Features&pageId=1
```

Is it possible to show only the Wiki, without the DevOps main menu on the left side (Overview, Summary, Dashboards, Wiki, Repos, Pipelines, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to show only the Wiki, without the DevOps main menu on
>   the left side (Overview, Summary, Dashboards, Wiki, Repos, Pipelines,
>   etc.)

As you can see from this link, this is the link which represent the whole page contained the left panel and right content displayed. If you want to use this link as the part of your WPF view, it may not be shown only wiki.

But there has an work around, since WPF support Markdown language, you can use the below  api to get the its markdown script:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/wiki/wikis/{wiki name}/pages/%2F10
```

[image]

And then, use these to used into your WPF script.

**Update:**

To use this API, you need to pass the credential to the script first. To supply the credential, you can link a `.cs` file which written with C#.

In this `.cs` file, use the follow C# script to get connect with your org:

```
var url = new Uri("https://dev.azure.com//{org}");
VssCredentials cre = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "{PAT token}"));
var connection = new VssConnection(url, cre);
var workitemClient = connection.GetClient<xxxxHttpClient>();
```

Comment: That's quite interesting, thank you! Do you know how I can supply credentials?

Comment: Which HttpClient did you use and which method? With the GitHttpClient and GetItemsAsync() I have to provide the repository and the path, but I don't see the wiki contents under "Repos" / "Files", so I think the correct way is using your url. But which client method then? Thanks again.

Comment: Since it is getting the content of wiki, so the method I used is Get. The HttpClient I used is WikiHttpClient. For some namespace and class, you can refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.wiki.webapi.wikipage?view=azure-devops-dotnet

Comment: How the things going? Did you have any other puzzle about it? Don’t hesitate to let us know.

Comment: I can download a single markdown page now but I don't see yet how to get the whole structure and navigate between pages. Also, to render markdown in WPF we need libraries, right, there is no WPF support for markdown I guess?

Comment: Yes, of course the library needed to render the markdown in WPF.  Refer to this         [third party render](https://github.com/lunet-io/markdig#third-party-extensions)

Comment: I tried this already, it seems to not convert the Umlauts and I don't know how to style the HTML but this is another topic now. Thanks for you help! :)

Comment: Since I does not too good at the markdown render in WPF, sorry for could not help you about this. If still have puzzle about C# and Azure Devops, just free to share it~~:)

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to share what we finally ended up with for our WPF "WikiView" user control:

- we use the WikiHttpClient's GetPageAsync() to get all pages' content (page.Page.Content) and save the markdown (*.md) files locally using the path name in page.Page.GitItemPath
- we use the GitHttpClient to get all images from the "attachments" folder within the wiki repository
- Markdig to convert the markdown to html (and manually fix absolute link addresses to relative ones)
- a ListBox for the wiki pages (table of contents)
- a CefSharp browser control to show the html (the WPF BrowserControl displayed images too small)

I will supply some code in case that's of interest.

Comment: I am surprised Azure DevOps Wiki's [CommonMark.](http://commonmark.org/) non-compliance did not present problems, e.g. "_# characters must be followed by spaces or tab_" is not enforced, non-standard [table of contents tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#table-of-contents-toc-for-wiki-pages), [Mermaid diagrams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#add-mermaid-diagrams-to-a-wiki-page) to name the few I've encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the wiki is actually markdown, you can always download the source and use a markdown viewer. E.g. VsCode markdown preview.